# Alfresco simple OCR. Extract text from PDF file and use it to start workflow

Tags: ocr, alfresco

I'm using [alfresco-simple-ocr](https://github.com/keensoft/alfresco-simple-ocr) with pdfsandwich and tesseract OCR. I want to get the text from a document inserted to a folder and then use the text and a pdf file in a new workflow.
 I've managed to do OCR extraction and how to start a workflow with a file inserted to catalogue, 
but I can't get text from file and use it in the workflow.
 Is there a possibility to do this?
 Where can I start implementing that function ? 
Greetings, Rafał

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any extension for that. Alfresco already integrates PDfBox that will do that for you. After, it depends of your PDF if it's a PDF containing images (so scanned documents) or if it's a PDF containing already text inside.
If you want to OCR some images, you have as well this module:
https://github.com/bchevallereau/alfresco-tesseract

When you know what you want to transform, you can look at this page where you have a javascript sample on how to call transformers:
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-extension-points-content-transformer.html
You can do that as well in Java if you need.